# Is there an easy way to change the hour of an existing time?

Tags: go, time

So far the best that I have is this, which is long and it's easy to make a mistake:

```
cst, _ := time.LoadLocation("Asia/Shanghai")
orig := time.Now().In(cst)
new := time.Date(orig.Year(), orig.Month(), orig.Day(), 13, orig.Minute(), orig.Second(), orig.Nanosecond(), cst)
fmt.Printf("%v", new)
```

https://play.golang.org/p/dv_7rltueY6

Comment: `time.Add(N * time.Hour)`, where `N` is an integer representing the number of hours you want to add (or subtract if `N` is negative).

Comment: Note that the result isn't always well-defined. The new instant might either not exist, or be ambiguous, during a DST changeover or other timezone shenanigans.

Comment: The correct answer depends on how you're using this derrived value. What is your goal?

Comment: @Flimzy I'm curious to see all the answers for all the possible goals.
But in my case there is the goal of setting the current datetime to a specific hour to perform an action at that hour or to swap the hour of an existing datetime for mocking. Something like `mytime.Hour(10)` would be great

Comment: If your goal is to do something "every day at X hour", then DST matters, to the extent that X may be duplicated or not exist on some dates. If your goal is "Do something in Y hours", then use `.Add()`, and DST will be accounted for. If your goal is "Do something on a specific date at a specific time", then DST matters. For mocking, DST may not matter (except when testing that your code works with DST). If you can get away with using UTC, then maybe you can avoid the DST issue entirely.

Comment: @Flimzy let's use the case where I want to get the statistics of a shop between opening and closing hours, these hours don't change even when DST changes.

Comment: That depends on whether or not the shop is ever open at 2am :)

Comment: If the shop's hours never cross midnight, then you might be able to ignore hours entirely, and just consider the date.

Comment: @Flimzy 9am to 5pm :)

Answer (score 1):

It may seem easier to do arithmetic with durations.

```
// NO!
// const newHour = 13
// d := orig.Add(time.Duration(newHour - orig.Hour()) * time.Hour)
```

However, this won't work during daylight savings. Your original code is about as correct as it can be... the `time.Date()` function will account for daylight savings, although there are certain edge cases with no good answer (what happens when you set the time to 1:30AM when the clocks go forward in North American eastern time?)

Comment: Thank you for sharing this gotcha, it's super useful.